# How to install third party libraries in a directory and include them as standard C headers

Tags: c

I'm used to got something like `npm i` in nodejs, or `pip install` in python to install/add 3rd party libraries but C has nothing of this.

Say I want to use this [orca](https://github.com/cee-studio/orca) library and use its headers as I'd use any other standard C headers like including stdlib (I want to be able to include them with *<>* instead of "") I dont get its build instructions,

- How would I get autocompletion in vim (I use clang and coc-clangd for C autocompletion) from these headers?
- How would the compiler know where these headers are located in? As first I thought adding them to the include dir in linux but didnt seem right
- If I wanted to make a C library for others to use, how would I set up everything for them to use it.
- If I wanted to use my own headers as standard C ones for my directory, how would do I so? Say I've got the following dir structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── include
    │   ├── header1.h
    │   └── header2.h
    ├── implement1.c
    ├── main.c
    └── implement2.c
```

And in the main.c I want to include header1.h as so...

```c
#include <header1.h>

int main() {
   header1Somefunction();
   return 0;
}
```

I use cmake for linking c executables.

Some time ago, I had kind of same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672342/why-cant-clang-find-napi-h-header-node-addon-api) creating a C addon for nodejs, with napi.h header file, where I couldn't include it as a standard header (which was in node_modules/node-addon-api) so I had to create that addon without autocompletion reading examples and docs and instead of napi.h I ended up using node/node_api.h, and I wasn't even able to include it as just node_api.h but node/node_api.h.

Comment: Notably, `#include "header.h"` first checks the local path and if nothing is found there, it checks the library path. So `#include <header.h>` provides no extra functionality. So why do you want the latter?

Comment: Well for orca, you would do `sudo make install` to install it system-wide.

Comment: Autocompletion of some editor is not a feature of the C infrastructure of your system. Vim just knows some common paths, as many other editors and IDEs do. I'm sure you can adjust a list of paths somewhere for vim. -- For the compiler, there are options to add paths to the list of searched paths.

Comment: Just to learn and because I saw some C repos in github and they were including its own headers as standar ones [here](https://github.com/sebbekarlsson/css)